# jQuery fader dots interactivity function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how do I go about implementing indicator dots within a fader that are clickable and function similarly to the code I have below. I.E., when the corresponding dot is clicked on, it fades to the corresponding image it is bound to? I have created the dots, and they can be converted into buttons for clickability, but how to I create a function, and what would that function be?

```js
function cycleImages() {
  var $active = $('.image.active'); //get the active tab
  var $next = $active.next().length > 0 ? $active.next() : $('.image:first');
  //check next length if not present just get the first .image div
  //fade out the top image and remove active class from it in callback
  $active.animate({
    opacity: '0'
  }, 400, function() {
    $active.removeClass('active')
    $next.animate({
      opacity: '1'
    }, 400, function() {
      $next.addClass('active');
    })
  });
}

// run every 5s
setInterval(cycleImages, 5000);
```

```css
div.image div.caption {
  display: visible;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 20;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.fader {
  border-radius: 1em;
  height: 25vw;
  width: 74vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 10vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1.5em solid #aa917d;
  border-right: 1.5em solid #aa917d;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fader div.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
div.image img {
  z-index: 5;
}

div.image{
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 1s ease-in;
}

div.image.active{
  opacity:1;
}

div.image:not(.active){
      display:none;  
}

.dots {
    float: right;
    background-color: rgba(65,45,30,0.5);
    border: none;
    border-radius: .85vw;
    display: inline-block;
    height: .85vw;
    width: .85vw;
    margin: .2em .2em .2em .2em;
}
.dots.active {
    background-color: #aa917d;
}

.dot-container {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: .5em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader">
  <div class="image active">
    <img class="" src="https://images.contentful.com/256tjdsmm689/2T0QeKcvR6MSsckuKoYIwS/b57d12107fc5eb635e294ed1c76cbbac/feature-gettyimages.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="image-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <div class="dot-container">
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots active"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="" src="http://www.livemint.com/rf/Image-621x414/LiveMint/Period2/2016/04/09/Photos/DNAnocredit-kuAC--621x414@LiveMint.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="image-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <div class="dot-container">
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots active"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738CEB00000578-3504412-image-a-4_1458654503277.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="image-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <div class="dot-container">
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots active"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img lass="" src="http://static.bigstockphoto.com/images/homepage/2016_bigstock_video.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="image-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <div class="dot-container">
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots active"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="" src="http://media.tinmoitruong.vn/public/media/media/picture/03/kh4.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:auto; object-fit: contain">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="image-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <div class="dot-container">
        <span class="dots active"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
        <span class="dots"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a few things to be able to navigate through the slides with the dots:

- Loop through the dot elements, applying an attribute to each dot (a number, beginning at 0 or 1) and incrementing by one for each dot.
- Loop through the images, applying an attribute to each images (a number, beginning at 0 or 1) and incrementing by one for each dot. (just like the dots)
- Adding an on click event handler to the dots that will get the number attribute of that particular dot and display the image with the same number attribute.
- Remove the markup for the dots that's on each slide and instead have only one set of dots for all slides (this will require tweaking of your HTML/CSS)

I would recommend looking at an existing carousel that has this functionality to get a better understanding of the code. Take a look at this [blog post from Barrel titled "Building a Responsive jQuery Carousel Plugin from Scratch.](http://www.barrelny.com/blog/building-a-jquery-slideshow-plugin-from-scratch/)" It has the functionality you're looking for.